# Почему nginx вместо выполнения php его скачивает в загрузки браузера?

Tags: php, nginx, сервер, веб-сервер, php-fpm

Не первый задаю здесь этот вопрос, тем не менее рецепт, который бы в моем случае сработал не нашел.. Вот конфиг моего виртуального хоста:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/compilationBot;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name compilationbot.local;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

В nginx.conf тоже вроде бы все включено.. php-fpm установлен работает...

/var/log/nginx/error.log

Последние записи:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хрустальный шар говорит что надо смотреть в логи. Ещё даёт 80% вероятность что в файле короткий открывающий тег (`<?`), а в конфиге PHP он не включен https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Comment: P.S. nginx не может выполнять или не выполнять PHP-файлы (и какие либо другие файлы).

Comment: @AlexeyTen добавил под вопросом скрин лога nginx, но если запустить compilationbot/index.php, а потом посмотреть в лог, то после самого этого события - скачивания php вместо исполнения в лог не заносится ничего..

Comment: @AlexeyTen, причем, что интересно. Положенный в директорию с виртуальным хостом, php на котором не исполняется файл test.php с простым кодом <?php echo 'hello'; выполняется в браузере.. а index.php c php кодом в той же папке нет

Comment: Скажите, а откуда вы вообще взяли эту конфигурацию? Почему не используете стандартную? И в чем смысл выкладывать конфиг  в котором используется include, но содержимое этого include не показывать?

Comment: @Ипатьев это стандартная, из default, которую я почти не менял.. include в ней закомментирован. а я раскомментил..

Answer (score -1):

дело было вот в чем:
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;

а в конфиге deafaul из коробки nginx почему-то var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock.

php7.4-fpm.sock я тоже не перемещал, у меня run не по тому пути расположен тоже по умолчанию, сразу после установки. Так что имейте в виду, кто будет nginx и WSL2 ставить в 2023 году